# STM32F4 host powering USB device using VBUS

Tags: usb, stm32, usb-host

I am trying to design an STM32F411 USB host. I will be connecting it to a USB MIDI device. The USB MIDI device I am using is AKAI Professional MPK Mini MKII which only has 1 USB port both for power and data which means that I need to power the device through USB.

From the STM32F411 datasheet, I have found some relevant circuit schematics:

[image]

However, I am unsure about the VBUS part. How am I supposed to power my USB device with microcontroller? My microcontroller logic is +3.3V and USB required +5V. Do I need to power USB device through VBUS pin on the microcontroller?

I have read somewhere that VBUS is used for sensing:

> The USB device is bus-powered, VBUS sensing is not mandatory (USB is always connected when the device is powered)

For my application, the microcontroller is going to be host only therefore I assume I don't even need to use the VBUS? Can I just connect the external +5V source to the USB VBUS pin instead?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing statements that apply when STM32 is USB device and when it is USB host. Yes, as a USB host, you need to have 5V supply at the connector for the USB device. The datasheet schematic is correct, the VDD is 5V and there is a switch component so MCU can control the port power and safely determine overcurrent situation. But the MCU is the host so it does not need to monitor the 5V supply at the connector with MCU VBUS pin. The 5V at USB connector just happens to be also named as VBUS.

Comment: Thanks for replying. What would happen if I supply external +5V supply to 5V pin at the connector? Could you give me an example of the "current limiter power switch" device as I am not able to find something relevant Also, is external oscilator necessary for USB host as I have seen most of the schematics examples use an external oscilator

Comment: If you just supply 5V to the USB connector, the STM32 cannot turn it on and off to reset the USB device. Best source to find a power switch is to look at STM32 evaluation kit boards, OnSemi and ST current limited power switches are popular there. Do you mean external crystal or external oscillator? Need of an external clock source depends entirely if the internal clock is accurate enough or not, and this reads in the datasheets. I would not spend time thinking about it, I would just put an external crystal there to avoid the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I have found an example as such : http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2236967.pdf?_ga=2.106935363.1138547534.1562581777-1983729434.1561632443&_gac=1.181669589.1562596112.CjwKCAjw04vpBRB3EiwA0IieagAWZbfcNhf8PCpC9eLWFBSHYdmOlWgRT7uhCNQ8v6GueJ8KXf3vIBoC0BsQAvD_BwE                                                                                              In the example schematic, the Vin is used as 5V, I assume that this will not do for me  as it needs to be powered from the VCC +3.3V ?

Comment: I think I have used that chip. Yes you really really need to give this power switch chip 5V in so it can give 5V out to your USB device. It simply does not work with 3.3V. If you make a USB host you need 5V power supply. What is your power source now? I mean the 3.3V must also come from somewhere, so why not 5V.

Comment: I have an external +5V source which I can use as VIN for that chip, however the FLAG pin is pulled to +5V and connected to one of the GPIO pins. I believe that is going to damage my GPIO pin?

Comment: STM32 does not use 5V logic. In general, you have a 5V supply for USB and 3.3V for STM32. It is up to your implementation how you want to generate them with what you have available. And I don't know what you have available.

Comment: Well there are two things. Don't pull up flag to 5V but to 3.3V. Or make sure you use 5V tolerant pin on STM32. Just look at how ST has designed their boards for USB host.

Comment: Thank you. Also, the MIDI device that I use is: AKAI Professional MPK Mini MKII . I cant seem to find current consumption for this device as I need to know what power supply to design

Comment: This is the beauty of USB, if you design it by the specs, it will work with all devices. Except those that are not built by the specs of course. So expect max 500mA consumption, but reserve a bit more, maybe 700-800mA. Or 1A.

Answer (score -1):

You need the voltage converter which will convert 3.3V VDD to 5V required by the USB. Vbus  uC pin does not power anything!!!! It is used in the device mode to sense the presence of the USB power.

Comment: Lots of USB devices are powered from VBUS.

Comment: @benvoigt really? Vbus STm32 uC pin? Show me one. This pin can source 10mA and is 3.3V.  So please show me any device powered by this pin

Comment: I'm talking about the VBUS pin on the USB connector, not on the microcontroller.  If you didn't mean the VBUS-pin-defined-by-the-USB-standard pin, it would be good to be clear (in your answer, not a comment) what pin you are talking about.

Comment: @benvoigt refer to the orinal question and schematics posted there. Did you dv me? Did you vote to delete my answer?

Comment: Referring to the schematic posted in the question, the only appearance of VBUS is on the USB-A connector.  That one does need to be supplied with +5V.  OP already has a 5V source, and should use that rather than using a boost converter fed by VDD.

Comment: @BenVoigt read the sentence below the picture (`Do I need to power USB device through VBUS pin on the microcontroller?`)

Comment: Yes, I agree there are two different VBUS pins.  Good that you edited your answer to say which one you are talking about.  Now if you had also read the last sentence of the question "Can I just connect the external +5V source to the USB VBUS pin instead?" you might not have given advice to add an unnecessary and inefficient boost converter.

Comment: @benvoigt if he has 5v available...  But he was confused be many Vbus signals and my answer is about the one he cannot use